# Can a javascript constructor function return a value?

Tags: javascript

I have created a constructor function and passing arguments in form of objects rather that creating multiple argument in calling function. The caller statement looks like this:

```
var isValid = _NonEmptyValidation({
                id:attributes.id,
                errorField:errorField,
                disableButtons:disableElements,
                errorMsg:"Please add a name to task"    
                })
```

Calling function is:

```
var _NonEmptyValidation = function(options){

        var validationField = document.getElementById(""+options.id+"").value;
        var checkEmptyWhiteSpace=  /^\s+$/;
        if(validationField.length >0 && !checkEmptyWhiteSpace.test(validationField)){
            return true;
            }
            else {
                for(var i =0,j=options.disableButtons.length;i<j;i++){
                            document.getElementById(""+options.disableButtons[i]+"").disabled=true;
                            }
                document.getElementById(""+options.errorField+"").innerHTML=options.errorMsg
                return false
                };
        }
```

But after the function execution when I am checking isValid i am not getting any returned value. Is there any way to get a returned value from this calling function

Comment: A constructor should return an object. This doesn't look like a constructor to me. Looks like just a regular function that would be called without `new`.

Comment: So, does that resolve your issue?

Comment: yes it resolved the issue

Comment: There is typo error at the closing curly bracket of the else block.. :)

Comment: Can you give an example how constructor function returns an object?